# Why does every prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is of the form $(f\otimes_R f)^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$ implies in kernel of $f\otimes_Rf$ be a nilideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $f: B \to B'$ be a $R-$algebra homomorphism whose kernel is a nilideal and $B'$ is integral over $f(B)$. It is clear that we have the induced $f\otimes_Rf:B\otimes_RB \to B'\otimes_RB'$. But why does every prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $B\otimes_RB$ is of the form $(f\otimes_R f)^{-1}(\mathfrak{q})$, $\mathfrak{q}$ prime of $B'\otimes_RB'$ implies in the kernel of $f\otimes_Rf$ be a nilideal?

Any help on this statement will be very appreciated! If this is in some book/article, please add some reference! Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f\otimes f$ is integral and its kernel consists of nilpotent elements. So we can suppose it is injective. Consider its localization morphism by the mutiplicable subset $(B\otimes_R B )\setminus \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @Acrobatic I've followed your hint, but I could not do it. Can you, please, write a answer? Thank you!